# TFS: Get specific directory before automatic build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

We have a directory in TFS (a team project) where all our internals and third parties DLL are referenced. It's works great, all our project references these directory.

When I configure an automatic build of my project, I would like that TFS automatically download the latest version of this directory, before TFS do my build. I could configure it?

By the way: We use VS2012 and TFS2012.

Thank you.

Comment: What's mean of before the build? Did you mean you need a pre-build script before the actual running of the build? Or you want to do this before the build triggered?

Comment: Well... 
1) Developper ask a build on project XYZ.
2) TFS download latest version of external dependencies directory. (HOW?)
3) TFS Build project XYZ.

Answer (score 0):

In a XAML build, map the TFVC folder where those assemblies are stored under the "Source Settings" tab.